# Remember passphase when using Windows cmd (git)

Tags: git, ssh, cmd, git-bash

I have Windows 10; installed git 2.6.1 (with no other separate ssh agents). Have set up SSH according to the tutorial from [Atlassian](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html). I am able to do `git push` to a remote repo over the Internet in git bash. I need to supply the passphrase once when I am logging in into my machine, I am fine with that. Then I can keep pushing with no prompts appearing.

My problem is that I want to push from an IDE which use the git cmd (`"c:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe"`) and there is no way to supply the passphrase in the IDE properties. When I start Windows cmd, and then run the command

`"c:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe" push ....path to my remote repo...`

I am getting the prompt to enter my passphrase. After doing that, the push happens and I can see it in the remote repo.

**How do I make git cmd application to re-use my passphrase? I want to be able to execute the push to remote repo running the cmd command above without being prompted to enter passphrase.**

Most of the questions are from those who get prompt in git bash; but here are things I have tried from other answers (they are just a few though) that were related to cmd:

- created a user env var HOME pointing to `C:\Users\myusername\`
- copied the rsa keys into the git install folder

Neither of those things helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, I run *git bash* when I start the machine and then enter my passphrase. This will keep me logged in as long as I don't log off or restart my machine, which is fine for me. Then I run the `env` command in the *git bash*, which gives me the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment generated. I then append this environment into my IDE's project environments and save.

This means I can push branch changes from my IDE into a remote git repo as long as the machine was not restarted (then the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment will change and I need to update my IDE's project environments).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to install http://gitcredentialstore.codeplex.com/ which store the credentials into windows ?
Download it from there even if the project just move to github (there is still not release to download from their... )

Comment: Thanks, @Philippe. Hope to avoid installing one more piece of software - let's wait until someone who can come up with the pure configuration solution...